# How to get shell before login in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, fedora

Is it possible to access a terminal before login into a user account? I cant login into fedora. The system boots and decrypts but the login screen loops forever doing nothing.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you check you keyboard , could it be some key has stayed pressed , did you also try login to the machine using putty ?

Comment: If the issue is with a GUI login, try to switch to a text terminal, e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2, Ctrl+Alt+F3 etc. Note on some laptops you need Fn+F2 to get the actual F2, so the whole stroke is like Ctrl+Alt+Fn+F2.

Comment: Hi! Yes the keyboard input has been verified. And no, I could not have used Putty because I could not even login in single user or recovery mode and have access to shell.

Answer (score 0):

The single user mode and rescue mode seems to be both unavailable with a locked shell.
After some more research, I ended up with a solution to at least backup the data using the root account.

For the key shortcuts, the machine is a MBP late 2013.

- In the grub screen press `e` to gain access to editing mode.
- Locate the line saying "kernel"
- Append at the end of the line `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh`
- Boot using F10
- `# passwd`->
  `# touch /.autorelabel`->
  `# reboot`

Comment: What does touching `/.autorelabel` do?